# What is the general formula for $\int h(x)$ if $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

The product rule is great for the derivatives, but I'm wondering if there is a similar general rule for integration when you have a function $h(x)$ that is the product of two functions that you know the integral for.

The context of this question is that I have a normal distribution and a linear function, and I want to know the integral of their product.

For example:

$$\text{NORMAL} = \mathcal{N}(100,12) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \cdot 12^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-100)^2}{2\cdot 12^2}}$$

$$\text{OTHER} = 12.95x + 26$$

I want the general way to find the integral of the product of two functions such as this.

A note on how this is being used, because it limits the types of solutions that are acceptable for my situation:

This formula is going to be implemented in a computer program, so *all* functions that I use must either be able to be evaluated with arithmetic, or have a convergent sum representation.

I have an implementation for the CDF for a normal distribution already created, so the integral of the normal function is something which I have available to use.

Here's an example of the limitations:

$$u = f(x | \mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \cdot \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\cdot \sigma^2}}$$

$$v' = g(x|a,b) = ax + b$$

$$h(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$$

From integration by parts, we know that:

$$\int{uv' \,dx} = uv - \int{u'v \,dx}$$

So we know that:

$$v = \int{ax+b \,dx} = \frac{ax^2}{2} + bx + C$$

$$u' = \frac{(\mu - x)}{\sigma^2 \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi \cdot \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\cdot \sigma^2}}$$

Now if I use integration by parts, I end up with this:

$$\int h(x) = \frac{\frac{ax^2}{2}+bx + C}{\sqrt{2 \pi \cdot \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\cdot \sigma^2}} - \int{\frac{(\mu - x)(\frac{ax^2}{2}+bx + C)}{\sigma^2 \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi \cdot \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\cdot \sigma^2}} \,dx}$$

But the integral on the right is just as difficult to calculate, and doesn't conform to the existing $\text{erf}$ I have already implemented for the normal distribution.

If I use the opposite form:

$$v' = f(x | \mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \cdot \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\cdot \sigma^2}}$$

$$u = g(x|a,b) = ax + b$$

$$v = \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$

$$u' = a$$

Then:

$$\int h(x) = \frac{ax+b}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] - \int{\frac{a}{\sqrt{2 \pi \cdot \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\cdot \sigma^2}}}$$

Is certainly simpler, but runs into the same problem of calculating the integral on the right.

Note that $a$, $b$, $\mu$, and $\sigma$ may all have arbitrary values, so I can't simplify them out of the formula.

EDIT: I believe I've found a workable answer that satisfies my problem, but would appreciate it if someone who understands the math better could check it for me:

$$\int h(x) = \frac{ax+b}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] - \frac{a}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] + \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$

Simplified:

$$\int h(x) = \frac{ax-a+b+1}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$

Or:

$$\int h(x) = (ax-a+b+1) \cdot \frac{1}{2}\left[1 + \operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$$

Or:

$$\int h(x) = (ax-a+b+1) \cdot \Phi (x)$$

Comment: There is integration by parts.

Comment: That would be challenging, considering that the derivative of the normal function is something I don't have an easy general solution to. I'm writing a computer program, so I'd need to simplify any equations I work with into a convergent sum or something that can be directly evaluated.

Comment: Does "numeric integration" count as "something that can be directly evaluated"? That's usually the best way to tackle this in software if you need any level of generality - of course, if you're just integrating polynomials against the PDFs of common probability distributions (or tasks like that), you can just pre-compute the values you need and look them up at run time (e.g. store a table of moments of your distribution)

Comment: I could do numeric integration if I really have to, however I'm attempting to build an implementation that allows for arbitrary precision in the answer, so numeric integration would be challenging to say the least. Also unfortunate is that the probability distributions have a wide variety of means and standard deviations, so precomputing those is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely a duplicate in spirit, but it's apparently tricky to find a suitable question to redirect you to.

There is indeed an analogue of the product rule for integration: If $u, v$ are functions of $x$, we can write the usual product rule as $$(uv)' = u v' + u' v,$$
and integrating gives
$$u v = \int u v' \,dx + \int u' v \,dx = \int u \,dv + \int v \,du$$ Rearranging gives the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) formula: $$\int u v' \,dx = uv - \int u' v \,dx .$$ We can see that if we wish to apply this formula, we must in particular integrate one of the factors of the original product.

To integrate our particular function, however, we don't need to use integration by parts: By making an appropriate affine change of variable $x \rightsquigarrow u$, we can rewrite the product
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \exp\left[-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right] \cdot (a x + b)$$
as $$A u e^{-u^2} + B e^{-u^2}$$ for some constants $A, B$. The first term can be integrated via substitution, but the second term has no closed-form antiderivative; often we express that antiderivative in terms of the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), $$\operatorname{erf}(u) = \frac{2}{\sqrt \pi} \int_0^u e^{-t^2} dt.$$

Putting this all together we find
$$\begin{multline}\color{#bf0000}{\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \exp\left[-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right] \cdot (a x + b) \,dx} \\ \color{#bf0000}{= \frac{1}{2} (a \mu + b) \operatorname{erf} \left(\frac{x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right) - \frac{a \sigma}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left[- \frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right] + C} . \end{multline}$$
We can alternatively write the second term on the right-hand side in your notation as $-a \sigma^2 f(x | \mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: I actually explored this option, however I ran into the issue that I'm using these solutions as part of a computer program. This limits the solutions I can use to things which have a convergent sum representation or can be directly evaluated.

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific (ideally in your question statement) about your constraints? There are many implementations of $\operatorname{erf}$.

Comment: I have an implementation of $\text{erf}$, the main problem is that the coefficients on the linear equation and the mean and standard deviation in the normal function will both change every time the application is run, so nothing can be pre-computed. I think the main blocker to using your answer for me is that I don't have a derivative for $\phi$ where $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are variable.

Comment: Alright, please see the expanded notes and explanation given in my question.

Comment: What is $\phi$? In any case, if you have a satisfactorily robust implementation of $\operatorname{erf}$, then I don't understand what you're looking for that you don't already have, as you can write the antiderivative of your product in terms of elementary functions and $\operatorname{erf}$. There's no need to precompute anything.

Comment: $\phi = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$. I need, in the end, the have a single function that can be calculated to a single number answer that takes as input the coefficients of the linear equation ($a$ and $b$), the mean and standard distribution of the PDF ($\mu$ and $\sigma$), and the $x$ value that I want the integral with respect to $x$ for. The only inputs I can have for this are $a$, $b$, $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $x$, and everything needs to be expressed in those terms. I've been trying to take the suggestions provided and then put it in terms of these numbers.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an explicit formula for the antiderivative in terms of the given parameters. (In particular, the don't think the expression you give for the same in your edit to the question is quite right.)

Comment: You're correct, my answer didn't work after I applied some test data to it, though I was at a loss as to why. This last answer you gave really showed me what you meant though about the substitution to avoid integration by parts. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found my explanation useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular case of $f(x)=u'(v(x))$ and $g(x)=v'(x)$ we have

$$\int h(x)dx = \int f(x)g(x)dx=\int u'(v(x))v'(x)dx=u(v(x)) +C$$

and as a more general method from the product rule for derivative

$$[u(x)v(x)]'=u'(x)v(x)+u(x)v'(x)$$

we can show that the following holds

$$\int u'(x)v(x)dx =u(x)v(x) -\int u(x)v'(x)dx$$

which is the well known formula for integration by parts.